# IE Cannot open the internet site (no JS on the page)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I know that there are many posts about this on Stackoverflow, but this one is different.

All of the other fixes to this have to do with javascript, but I don't even have javascript on my page.  None.  And I am still getting this error.

Was there any other reasons why this error was being caused?

**Also, it only happens when I visit my top navigation links, rather than the page directly from the url.**  Take a look at:
http://www.mayandivers.com/see

EDIT: This is happening in IE6/7.

Comment: Sorry, yes, only IE6/7, pretty sure this buy was fixed by MS in IE8.

Comment: Erm, for those of us that don't have IE6/7 handy, what's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use *.htc files. Your site serves them as "text/html"
To make older versions of IE happy change the content type to "text/x-component"

http://scarfoo.com/archives/16

Comment: Ok, I changed that, but it still seems like it is occurring, just not as frequent.

Comment: Then the problem is that one of HTC files tries to modify DOM before the document is fully loaded. I will post another answer for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: HTC files (scripts in these files) try to modify DOM before the document finished loading.

Solution: either move your scripts to the bottom of the document (which you can't since they reside in the CSS declaration) or delay the execution of the scripts to allow browser to finish loading the document.

First of all - try removing reference(s) to iepngfix.htc and see if it fixes the issue.

If it doesn't help then let's have a look at another file that you use - border-radius.htc

You have this line:

```
<public:attach event="oncontentready" onevent="oncontentready('v08vnSVo78t4JfjH')" />
```

which in its turn calls this function:

```
function oncontentready(classID)
```

We need to add a small delay. Can you please try something like this?

```
<public:attach event="oncontentready" onevent="oncontentreadydelayed()" />
    function oncontentreadydelayed()
       {
       window.setTimeout(oncontentready('v08vnSVo78t4JfjH'), 1);  
       }
```